# Show and hide a td in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and wants to toggle a td content on td click. just like accordian. I have tried this code but of no use.

```
$('#table tr').each(function(){
        $(this).on("click", "#largeTd", function(){
            //$(this).toggle();
            //$('#largeTd:eq(' + index + ')',this).toggle();
        });

    });
```

How could I solve this issue.

Below is the HTML code which will be having a large text in a td. I want to show/hide this content on td click.

```
<table>
<tbody>                      
   <tr>
    <td align="">
                Text
                        </td>
                        <td class="largeTd">
                            <p> 

                                    large Text                                      
                                    <br>

                                    large Text
                                    <br>

                            </p>
                        </td>                                                                          
                    </tr>                                               

                    <tr>
                        <td align="">
                            Text4
                        </td>
                        <td class="largeTd">
                            <p> 

                                    large Text
                                    <br>

                                    large Text
                                    <br>

                            </p>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: I would advise against hiding table cells directly - it causes layout issues. It would be better to hide the content within the cell.

Comment: id be unique in html

Comment: hiding `tr` or a `td` ?

Comment: guess he wants to hide a td inside the clicked tr. #largeTd should be a class instead: .largeTd

Comment: @Mohammad Adil actually on td click hide/show a content

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. I  have updated my question you are right, I want to toggle a td content not a td.

Answer (score 1):

using find selector to find p when td is clicked

```
$('table tr td').click(function(){
        $("p",this).toggle();
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c0gsgery/5/)**

or using align attribute

```
$('table tr td[align]').click(function(){
        $(this).next("td").find("p").toggle();
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c0gsgery/6/)**

Comment: @Java_NewBie Show your html

Comment: I have posted the html

Comment: yes Thankyou. But I have done in the same selector e.g this $("p",this).toggle(); it also worked like this

Comment: Thankyou, using same selector.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you shouldn't hide a td but it's contents instead.
Also if each row has a td with the same id it might create problems. Try to replace it with a class instead:

```
$('#table tr').each(function(){
        $(this).on("click", ".largeTd>p", function(){
            $(this).toggle();
            //$('#largeTd:eq(' + index + ')',this).toggle();
        });

    });
```

I've updated your code by pretending that you putted the content in largeTd inside a `<p>` tag and replaced each `id="largeTd"` with `class="largeTd"`.

If this isn't what you want, you should give us your html code so that we know what you really want to obtain.

Comment: yes the idea is to hide a content rather a td, on td click hide its content and show its content

Comment: I am able to hide a content, but when I again click on a td it is not showing a content. The clicks works for only one time.